# How do I search for web pages that include a JavaScript file with a certain name?

Tags: search

I wrote an open source JavaScript library called [ObjectId.js](https://github.com/justaprogrammer/ObjectId.js). I'd like to know who is using it. I assume most people (if anyone is using it) are including a local copy of ObjectId.js in their web folder and including it via:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to/ObjectId.js"/>
```

So my question is: can I search Google, Bing etc. for web pages that include a JavaScript file called ObjectId.js?

Comment: Does `inurl:ObjectId.js` work?

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at MAMA (MAMA is a structural Web-page search engine).

- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/mama/
- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/mama-key-findings/

The reason why you can’t search Google/Bing is that they do not index the whole page. They parse through it and take out the HTML tags and any extra information they don't need, like scripts/HTML tags etc. and index the left over text. And that is what you search.

**EDIT**
They do store a cache of the full page's HTML, but this does not mean that it is indexed. They will only index the viewable text that end users can read.

Comment: Ok I feel pretty stupid, buy I can't find the link for the form I can start searching with.

Comment: For anyone else looking, the links above no longer work. you could instead use https://publicwww.com though this has a freemium pricing model.